# How to connect a MongoDb atlas database with Jaspersoft studio

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, jaspersoft-studio

I'm developing a Java Spring boot application with MongoDb database (MongoDB Atlas) and trying to generate reports from backend with Jasper reporting services. I have followed several tutorials to do that. But all of them show how to connect to a local database. Since I'm using MongoDB Atlas I'm wondering how to give Mongo URI while setting up the Data Adapter (See image)

[image]

If anyone knows a better approach to generate reports without using Japer reporting, please mention that as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have mongodb atlas properly setup before you can connect to it.

First click on Database Access under Security in mongo atlas dashboard and create a new user

[image]

Then click on Network Access again under Security and whitelist your IP. The following image allows anyone to connect to the db

[image]

Finally, go to your cluster and click connect and you will be presented the following dialog. Copy the connection string from it and paste it into your jaspersoft connected interface.

Make sure you replace the `<password>` with the password of the user created above

[image]

That should work!

**UPDATE:** here is a screenshot of successful connection to jasperreport studio

[image]

Comment: I already have set up a MongoDB cluster, DB user, and everything. What I can't figure out is what to put in mongo URI when setting up the data adapter in Jaspersoft studio.I have tried many ways without luck

Comment: The mongo url is in the last image i added and looks like this

`mongodb+srv://user_12345:your_password@cluster0-l6tmi.mongodb.net/test.........`

Copy this uri from your dashboard. Read the end of my post for details

Comment: @Affef Janjua As I said I have that connection string from MongoDb cluster. Have you tried putting it into jaspersoft studio and create the connection

Comment: @oshan2csd I have updated the answer with a screenshot of successful connection with jasperreport studio